# Simplifying $\frac{x^2y + xy^2}{y^2 + \frac{2}{5}xy}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A bit confused on how to simplify the fraction below:

$$\dfrac{x^2y + xy^2}{y^2 + \frac{2}{5}xy}$$

Initially, I cancelled the numerator and denominator of $y^2$, where in the numerator there is only $x^2y + x$. However, for the denominator should the 5, in 2/5 be multiplied with the numerator to help simplify?

Comment: I think your formatting of the fraction is incorrect: you are missing some parentheses.

Comment: strictly speaking $2/5xy$ means $\frac{2}{5}xy$. Is that what you mean? Just making sure you're not going for $2/(5 xy)$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I recommend you think of simplifying fractions like this in terms of multiplying by $1$. For example, $1 = \frac{5/2}{5/2}$: Multiply through by this and what do you get? Another fancy $1$ you might consider is $1 = \frac{1/(xy)}{1/(xy)}$. Multiply through and what do you get? Just choose the special $1$ which makes the result as simple as possible. With experience, the choice becomes obvious

Comment: If you intend to "cancel $y^2$" you really mean dividing the numerator and denominator by $y^2$.  As two of the terms only have $y$ in them you will have a $y$ in a new denominator.  That is not progress.  You can cancel $y$ usefully, but not $y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can write$$\frac{5x^2y+5xy^2}{5y^2+2xy}=\frac{5x^2+5xy}{5y+2x}$$ for $$y\neq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $y\ne0$, this is

$$5\frac{x^2+xy}{5y+2x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of confusion about what is meant by the word "canceling".

In general, if a factor [not an addend (which is a number that is added), but a factor (which is a number that is multiplied)] is present in the numerator as well as the denominator, it can be canceled.

$$\frac{ac}{bc} = \frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{c} = \frac{a}{b}\cdot 1 = \frac{a}{b}$$

An elementary school example of this idea would be
$$\frac{15}{24} = \frac{5\times 3 }{8\times 3} = \frac{5}{8}\times \frac{3}{3} = \frac{5}{8}\times 1 = \frac{5}{8}$$

Moving into higher grades, we did the same thing, but it took this form instead
$$\frac{15x^2y}{24xy^3} = \frac{3\cdot5\cdot xy\cdot x}{3\cdot8\cdot xy\cdot y^2}=\frac{(3xy)(5x)}{(3xy)(8y^2)}=\frac{3xy}{3xy}\cdot\frac{5x}{8y^2}=1\cdot\frac{5x}{8y^2}=\frac{5x}{8y^2}$$

Although we canceled $3xy$ as a single number, we could have canceled each of it's components separately
$$\frac{3xy}{3xy}=\frac{3\cdot xy}{3\cdot xy}=\frac{3}{3}\cdot\frac{xy}{xy}=1\cdot\frac{xy}{xy}=\frac{xy}{xy}= \text{etc.}$$

The difficulty with the expression that you provided is that we have a ratio of two sums, not two products, so we need to factor the numerator and denominator by using the "distributive property" [e.g. $ab+ac=a(b+c)$].

$$\frac{x^2y+xy^2}{y^2+\frac{2}{5}xy} = \frac{y(x^2+xy)}{y(y+\frac{2}{5}x)} = \frac{y}{y}\cdot\frac{x^2+xy}{y+\frac{2}{5}x} = 1\cdot\frac{x^2+xy}{y+\frac{2}{5}x} = \frac{x^2+xy}{y+\frac{2}{5}x}$$

We just "canceled" out a $y$, but it's just as easy to cancel out $\frac{1}{5}$ from the resultant expression.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+xy}{y+\frac{2}{5}x}&=\frac{\frac{5}{5}x^2+\frac{5}{5}xy}{\frac{5}{5}y+\frac{2}{5}x} = \frac{\frac{5}{5}\cdot\frac{x^2}{1}+\frac{5}{5}\cdot\frac{xy}{1}}{\frac{5}{5}\cdot\frac{y}{1}+\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{x}{1}}= \frac{\frac{5x^2}{5\cdot 1}+\frac{5xy}{5\cdot 1}}{\frac{5y}{5\cdot 1}+\frac{2x}{5\cdot 1}} = \frac{\frac{1\cdot 5x^2}{5\cdot 1}+\frac{1\cdot 5xy}{5\cdot 1}}{\frac{1\cdot 5y}{5\cdot 1}+\frac{1\cdot 2x}{5\cdot 1}}= \frac{\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{5x^2}{1}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{5xy}{1}}{\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{5y}{1}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{2x}{1}}\\
&=  \frac{\frac{1}{5}\cdot 5x^2+\frac{1}{5}\cdot5xy}{\frac{1}{5}\cdot5y+\frac{1}{5}\cdot2x} = \frac{\frac{1}{5}(5x^2+5xy)}{\frac{1}{5}(5y+2x)} = \frac{\frac{1}{5}}{\frac{1}{5}}\cdot\frac{5x^2+5xy}{5y+2x} = 1\cdot\frac{5x^2+5xy}{5y+2x}\\
&=\frac{5x^2+5xy}{5y+2x} = \frac{5(x^2+xy)}{5y+2x}
\end{align}$$

Okay, well maybe "easy" wasn't exactly the right word to use. Typically though, the short version would look more like this
$$\frac{x^2+xy}{y+\frac{2}{5}x}=\frac{\frac{5}{5}x^2+\frac{5}{5}xy}{\frac{5}{5}y+\frac{2}{5}x}=\frac{\frac{1}{5}(5x^2+5xy)}{\frac{1}{5}(5y+2x)} = \frac{5x^2+5xy}{5y+2x} = \frac{5(x^2+xy)}{5y+2x}$$

And lastly, another way that you could have canceled out the $\frac{1}{5}$ is just by multiplying the entire expression by  $\frac{5}{5}$
$$\frac{x^2+xy}{y+\frac{2}{5}x} = 1\cdot \frac{x^2+xy}{y+\frac{2}{5}x} = \frac{5}{5}\cdot \frac{x^2+xy}{y+\frac{2}{5}x}= \dots$$

which, I'll leave up to you as an exercise to complete.

And, remember that it's okay to use "tricks" to speed things along, but you need to understand how the tricks work before using them.